# Python - inserting a variable(list of more than one number)

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, insert

i want to insert a piece of punctuation in a list at a index in another list into a sentence:

```
for x in range(len(final1)):
    final1.insert(punc_num[x], punct[x])- WHY WONT THIS WORK?
```

Any help is kindly appreciated :-)

Whole Code:

```
f = open("file.txt","r") 
sentence= f.read()
print (sentence)

punctuations = ("'", "!", "(", ")", "-", "[", "]", "{", "}", ";", ":", '"', "<", ">", ".", "/", "?", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "_", "~", ",")

punc_num=[]

for x in sentence:
    if x in punctuations:
        punc_num.append(sentence.index(x))

print(punc_num)


punct=[]

for x in sentence:
    if x in punctuations:
        punct.append(x)

print(punct)





no_punct= ""

for y in sentence:
    if y not in punctuations:
        no_punct = no_punct + y

print (no_punct)





no_punct=no_punct.split()

final= (" ".join(sorted(set(no_punct), key=no_punct.index)))
print(final)
storing=[]

for x in no_punct:

    storing.append (no_punct.index(x))

print (storing)


final1= (" ".join(sorted(set(no_punct), key=no_punct.index)))
print(final1)




for x in range(len(final1)):
    final1.insert(punc_num[x], punct[x])
```

Comment: 1. `str` has no `insert` method.  2. If you are thinking of the `list.insert()` method, its arguments should be `index, object`, not `object, object`.

Comment: Well if I split the sentence into a list how would I insert the index(which is in the list)

Comment: Actually, my second point is not valid; you *were* using a number.  To get the result you want, you should put `no_punct_list = list(no_punct)` before your `for` loop, and then use `no_punct_list` rather than `no_punct` when you call `insert()`.  After your `for` loop, you can then say `no_punct = "".join(no_punct_list)`.  If this solves your problem, I'll put it in an answer.

Comment: Thankyou this is really helpful would that but both pieces of punctuation in the correct indexes I the list?

Comment: Not necessarily.  When you define `punc_num`, you use the `list.index()` method.  That will always return the *first* occurrence, not necessarily the one you want.  I'll add an answer with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use `final1.insert()`, `final1` is a string, not a list.  You can update it by doing this:

```
final1_list = []
for x in range(len(punc_num)):
    final1_list.insert(punc_num[x], punct[x])
final1 = "".join(final1_list)
```

Second, when you define `punc_num`, you use the `list.index()` method.  Since `list.index()` will always return the *first* occurrence of its argument, any given punctuation mark will always have the same index, regardless of how many places it appears in your string.  You can change that loop to this:

```
punc_num=[]
for x in sentence:
    if x in punctuations:
        index = 0
        while index + sentence[index:].index(x) in punc_num:
            index += sentence[index:].index(x) + 1
        punc_num.append(index + sentence[index:].index(x))
```

Your whole program should look like this:

```
f = open("file.txt","r")
sentence = f.read()
print (sentence)

punctuations = ("'", "!", "(", ")", "-", "[", "]", "{", "}", ";", ":", '"', "<", ">", ".", "/", "?", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "_", "~", ",")

punc_num=[]

for x in sentence:
    if x in punctuations:
        index = 0
        while index + sentence[index:].index(x) in punc_num:
            index += sentence[index:].index(x) + 1
        punc_num.append(index + sentence[index:].index(x))

print(punc_num)


punct=[]

for x in sentence:
    if x in punctuations:
        punct.append(x)

print(punct)





no_punct= ""

for y in sentence:
    if y not in punctuations:
        no_punct = no_punct + y

print (no_punct)



no_punct=no_punct.split()

final= (" ".join(sorted(set(no_punct), key=no_punct.index)))
print(final)
storing=[]

for x in no_punct:

    storing.append (no_punct.index(x))

print (storing)


final1= (" ".join(sorted(set(no_punct), key=no_punct.index)))
print(final1)




final1_list = list(final1)
for x in range(len(punc_num)):
    final1_list.insert(punc_num[x], punct[x])
final1 = "".join(final1_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for wasting your time but i'm trying to add the punctuation back in the sentence from the sentence without punctuation(no_punct) and the list of where the indexs of the punctuation are (punc_num) and the punctuation (punct) thank you so much. when i run this it says:

Comment: >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
hello my, name is dan.

[8, 21]
[',', '.']
hello my name is dan

hello my name is dan
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
hello my name is dan
[]

Comment: code: 
no_punct=no_punct.split()
final= (" ".join(sorted(set(no_punct), key=no_punct.index)))
print(final)
storing=[]

for x in no_punct:
    
    storing.append (no_punct.index(x))
print (storing)
final1= (" ".join(sorted(set(no_punct), key=no_punct.index)))
print(final1)
punc_num=[]
for x in sentence:
    if x in punctuations:
        index = 0
        while index + sentence[index:].index(x) in punc_num:
            index += sentence[index:].index(x) + 1
            punc_num.append(index + sentence[index:].index(x))

Comment: I made a mistake; it should be `len(punc_num)`, not `len(final1)`.  I have updated my answer with the full program.

Comment: thats fantastic thanks one last question how do i join this into a string:

Comment: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'y', ',', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'd', 'a', 'n', '.']

Comment: If your list is called `my_list`, you can say `my_string = "".join(my_list)`.